# how to use haben and worden_sein in a sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, grammatical-case

i am learning germam and my current proficiency level is B1
in this link:https://deutschegrammatik20.de/spezielle-verben/modalverben/subjektive-modalverben-zeitformen/
the following two sentences exists

```
aktiv: Man muss das Auto gestohlen haben. (=Ich bin sicher, dass man das Auto gestohlen hat.)
passiv: Das Auto muss gestohlen worden sein. (=Ich bin sicher, dass das Auto gestohlen worden ist.)
```

i want to use the following sentence in different teses similar to the aforementioned ones, the sentence is:

```
Die Koalition hat sich auf neue Heizungsgetz verständigt
```

**my attemps**

```
1. Die neue Heizungsgetz muss sich verständigt haben

2. Die neue Heizungsgetz muss sich verständigt worden sein
```

are my attempts correct and make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately both attempts are wrong and even the intended meaning remains unclear. The main problem is, that *verständigen* (as English *agree*) requires an actor doing the agreement, but the *HeizungsgeSEtz* (note the uppercase letters, which are missing in the quote of the question) is totally passive and so can't be combined easily.

*Sich* as reflexive pronoun relates to *Koalition* in the quote and not to the law.

Proper answers could be:

> Die Koalition muss sich auf ein neues Heizungsgesetz verständigt haben.
> Das neue Heizungsgesetz muss verabschiedet worden sein.

Answer (score 2):

Since the sentence lacks a proper accusative object which could serve as the subject in the equivalent passive sentence, the only possible way to convert this sentence into passive while still using *sich verständigen* is an impersonal passive:

> Es ist sich seitens der Koalition auf ein neues Heizungsgesetz verständigt worden.

or with *müssen*:

> Es muss sich seitens der Koalition auf ein neues Heizungsgesetz verständigt worden sein.

which is a bit weird but syntactically legal IMHO.